# Correlations between symbol color, viewer response and viewer mood

Tags: color, mood, imagery

Consider the image shown below

[image]

Are there any studies that look at how the viewer's response to such images - simple monocolor outline symbols - varies depending on their mood.  For instance

- Tense and agitated viewer responds best to red wine glass
- Relaxed viewer responds best to blue wine glass
- Happy user responds best to green wine glass
- ...